# Removing element from a javascript object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to search the solution alot but no one really helped me.

I have a javascript object:

```
trucks_obj
= Object {95: _.Kd, 96: _.Kd}

95: _.Kd
96: _.Kd
__proto__: Object
```

If the if condition is true, I just want to remove element from trucks_obj with specific ID. e.g. I need to remove element with 95 index. 
I have already tried splice() as well as slice() but nothing worked.

**Deletion Code**:

```
$.each(trucks_obj,function(i,e){
            if(($.inArray(i, trucks_arr)) === -1){
                trucks_obj.splice(i,1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
delete trucks_obj['95']
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. is it possible to delete an element of object on which we running, $.each()?

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(trucks_obj);` will return you array of keys . keys[i] will give you the current key. then you can use `delete trucks_obj[keys[i]];`

Comment: it's not a good idea to delete the reference you are actually iterate on. so no. a workaround may be another array with the properties to delete and iterate over the array and delete the properties of the object.

Comment: @Shubham, that works.

Comment: `delete` is a native Javascript function. A jquery object is not 100% compatible to a plain Javascript object

Comment: @NinaScholz The author asked for a way with Jquery

Comment: @reporter, "A jquery object is not 100% compatible to a plain Javascript object" do you know other objects in javascript who are not javascript objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz you cannot not apply all nativ js methods to a jquery object. The browser will show an 'element is undefined error' message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97567/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-reporter).